# Ember Octane vs old Ember the ability of using `reopen()` method

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I working on converting a them main `app.js` file over to Ember 4 and native javascript.  My question is how are people handling modifying things like the `Route` class.  My current portion of codes look like this.

```
Route.reopen({
  //breadCrumb: null
  currentRouteModel: function () {
    return this.modelFor(this.routeName);
  }
});
```

I mean i guess i can rewrite the instance case of method everywhere to just do exactly what it is returning, but I wanted to see what people are doing.  I also have a `Component` reopen on `app.js` that I need to fix in the migration.

Answer (score 1):

the main thing I've seen folks do is one of two things:

- copy the code into the places that use it
- make a class-decorator and apply that to the classes that need it

A class decorator would look something like this (and would only work in JS, and TypeScript doesn't know how "maybe"-inheritance works with class decorators (ok, it would technically "work" in TS, but you'd get type-errors)):

```js
// usage
@withCurrentRouteModel
export default class MyRoute extends Route {}

// implementation
function withCurrentRouteModel(OriginalRoute) {
  return class extends OriginalRoute {
    @service router;

    get routeName() {
      return this.router.currentRouteName;
    }

    get currentRouteModel() {
      this.modelFor(this.routeName);
    }

  }
}
```

I added a usage of the [RouterService](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/RouterService)

because I wasn't familiar with `routeName`

Comment: `routeName` is a property of the `Route` class: https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.3/classes/Route/properties/routeName?anchor=routeName It is the name of the route, for which the `Route` instance is. Not of the current active route.